# html css file note displaying image using jinga format for django

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

my index.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% static "images" as baseurl %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Travello</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Travello template project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
<link href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/main_styles.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/responsive.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'index.css"' %}>
</head>
<body>

<div class="super_container">

    <!-- Header -->

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="header_content d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                        <div class="header_content_inner d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                            <div class="logo"><a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">Travello</a></div>
                            <nav class="main_nav">
                                <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">About us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="accounts/register">Register</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{% static 'news.html' %}">News</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            <div class="header_phone ml-auto">Call us: 00-56 445 678 33</div>

                            <!-- Hamburger -->

                            <div class="hamburger ml-auto">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header_social d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Menu -->

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu_header d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
            <div class="menu_logo"><a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">Travello</a></div>
            <div class="menu_close_container ml-auto"><div class="menu_close"><div></div><div></div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{% static 'inex.html' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% static 'news.html' %}">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_social">
            <div class="menu_phone ml-auto">Call us: 00-56 445 678 33</div>
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Home -->

    <div class="home">

        <!-- Home Slider -->
        <div class="home_slider_container">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home_slider">

                <!-- Slide -->
                <div class="owl-item">
                    <div class="background_image" style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)' %}"></div>
                    <div class="home_slider_content_container">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="home_slider_content">
                                        <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Slide -->
                <div class="owl-item">
                    <div class="background_image" style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)' %}"></div>
                    <div class="home_slider_content_container">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="home_slider_content">
                                        <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Slide -->
                <div class="owl-item">
                    <div class="background_image" style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)' %}"></div>
                    <div class="home_slider_content_container">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="home_slider_content">
                                        <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="home_page_nav">
                <ul class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
                    <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#destinations">Offers<span>01</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#testimonials">Testimonials<span>02</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-scroll-to="#news">Latest<span>03</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Search -->

    <div class="home_search">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="home_search_container">
                        <div class="home_search_title">Search for your trip</div>
                        <div class="home_search_content">
                            <form action="#" class="home_search_form" id="home_search_form">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-lg-between justify-content-start">
                                    <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_1" placeholder="City" required="required">
                                    <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_2" placeholder="Departure" required="required">
                                    <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_3" placeholder="Arrival" required="required">
                                    <input type="text" class="search_input search_input_4" placeholder="Budget" required="required">
                                    <button class="home_search_button">search</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Intro -->

    <div class="intro">
        <div class="intro_background" style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/intro.png)' %}"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="intro_container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <!-- Intro Item -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
                                <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div class="intro_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/beach.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="intro_content">
                                        <div class="intro_title">Top Destinations</div>
                                        <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Intro Item -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
                                <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div class="intro_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/wallet.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="intro_content">
                                        <div class="intro_title">The Best Prices</div>
                                        <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Sollicitudin mauris lobortis in.</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Intro Item -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4 intro_col">
                                <div class="intro_item d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div class="intro_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/suitcase.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="intro_content">
                                        <div class="intro_title">Amazing Services</div>
                                        <div class="intro_subtitle"><p>Nulla pretium tincidunt felis, nec.</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Destinations -->

    <div class="destinations" id="destinations">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <div class="section_subtitle">simply amazing places</div>
                    <div class="section_title"><h2>Popular Destinations</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row destinations_row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="destinations_container item_grid">

                        <!-- Destination -->
                        {% for dest in dests %}
                        <div class="destination item">
                            <div class="destination_image">
                                <img src="{{baseurl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="">
                                {% if dest.offer %}
                                <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="destination_content">
                                <div class="destination_title"><a href="{% static 'destinations.html' %}">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
                                <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.dest}}</p></div>
                                <div class="destination_price">{{dest.price}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Testimonials -->

    <div class="testimonials" id="testimonials">
        <div class="parallax_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="{% static 'images/testimonials.jpg' %}" data-speed="0.8"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <div class="section_subtitle">simply amazing places</div>
                    <div class="section_title"><h2>Testimonials</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row testimonials_row">
                <div class="col">

                    <!-- Testimonials Slider -->
                    <div class="testimonials_slider_container">
                        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme testimonials_slider">

                            <!-- Slide -->
                            <div class="owl-item text-center">
                                <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
                                <div class="testimonial_author">
                                    <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                        <div>john turner,</div>
                                        <div>client</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Slide -->
                            <div class="owl-item text-center">
                                <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
                                <div class="testimonial_author">
                                    <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                        <div>john turner,</div>
                                        <div>client</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Slide -->
                            <div class="owl-item text-center">
                                <div class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. lobortis dolor. Cras placerat lectus a posuere aliquet. Curabitur quis vehicula odio.</div>
                                <div class="testimonial_author">
                                    <div class="testimonial_author_content d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                        <div>john turner,</div>
                                        <div>client</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="test_nav">
            <ul class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
                <li><a href="#">City Breaks Clients<span>01</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cruises Clients<span>02</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">All Inclusive Clients<span>03</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- News -->

    <div class="news" id="news">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-8">
                    <div class="news_container">

                        <!-- News Post -->
                        <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
                            <div class="news_post_image"><img src="{% static 'images/news_1.jpg' %}" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="news_post_content">
                                <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div>02</div>
                                    <div>june</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
                                <div class="news_post_category">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_text">
                                    <p>Pellentesque sit amet elementum ccumsan sit amet mattis eget, tristique at leo. Vivamus massa.Tempor massa et laoreet.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- News Post -->
                        <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
                            <div class="news_post_image"><img src="{% static 'images/news_2.jpg' %}" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="news_post_content">
                                <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div>01</div>
                                    <div>june</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
                                <div class="news_post_category">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_text">
                                    <p>Tempor massa et laoreet malesuada. Pellentesque sit amet elementum ccumsan sit amet mattis eget, tristique at leo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- News Post -->
                        <div class="news_post d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
                            <div class="news_post_image"><img src="images/news_3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="news_post_content">
                                <div class="news_post_date d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-start">
                                    <div>29</div>
                                    <div>may</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_title"><a href="#">Best tips to travel light</a></div>
                                <div class="news_post_category">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">lifestyle & travel</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news_post_text">
                                    <p>Vivamus massa.Tempor massa et laoreet malesuada. Aliquam nulla nisl, accumsan sit amet mattis.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- News Sidebar -->
                <div class="col-xl-4">
                    <div class="travello">
                        <div class="background_image" style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/travello.jpg)' %}"></div>
                        <div class="travello_content">
                            <div class="travello_content_inner">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="travello_container">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-end">
                                    <span class="travello_title">Get a 20% Discount</span>
                                    <span class="travello_subtitle">Buy Your Vacation Online Now</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="parallax_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/footer_1.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="newsletter">
                        <div class="newsletter_title_container text-center">
                            <div class="newsletter_title">Subscribe to our newsletter to get the latest trends & news</div>
                            <div class="newsletter_subtitle">Join our database NOW!</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="newsletter_form_container">
                            <form action="#" class="newsletter_form d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between" id="newsletter_form">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between">
                                    <div><input type="text" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_name" id="newsletter_input_name" placeholder="Name" required="required"><div class="input_border"></div></div>
                                    <div><input type="email" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_email" id="newsletter_input_email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required="required"><div class="input_border"></div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div><button class="newsletter_button">subscribe</button></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row footer_contact_row">
                <div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-1">
                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
                        <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
                            <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
                                <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/sign.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_title">give us a call</div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_list">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Office Landline: +44 5567 32 664 567</li>
                                        <li>Mobile: +44 5567 89 3322 332</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
                        <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
                            <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
                                <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/trekking.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_title">come & drop by</div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_list">
                                    <ul style="max-width:190px">
                                        <li>4124 Barnes Street, Sanford, FL 32771</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Footer Contact Item -->
                        <div class="col-xl-4 footer_contact_col">
                            <div class="footer_contact_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
                                <div class="footer_contact_icon"><img src="{% static 'images/around.svg' %}" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_title">send us a message</div>
                                <div class="footer_contact_list">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>youremail@gmail.com</li>
                                        <li>Office@yourbusinessname.com</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center"><!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --> </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/Isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/easing/easing.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

it's css fil:

```
body{
  background-image:{static %'url(E:\coding\fyp\travello\images\whyl)' %};

}
```

the console log:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 05, 2020 - 06:49:10
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'travel.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Apr/2020 06:49:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20811
Not Found: /index.css
[05/Apr/2020 06:49:20] "GET /index.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2363
Not Found: /images/news_3.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:49:21] "GET /images/news_3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2387

Not Found: /images/footer_1.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:49:21] "GET /images/footer_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2393
[05/Apr/2020 06:50:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20811
Not Found: /index.css
[05/Apr/2020 06:50:43] "GET /index.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2363
Not Found: /images/news_3.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:50:43] "GET /images/news_3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2387
Not Found: /images/footer_1.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:50:43] "GET /images/footer_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2393
[05/Apr/2020 06:52:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20820
[05/Apr/2020 06:52:12] "GET /static/index.css%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 1666
Not Found: /images/news_3.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:52:12] "GET /images/news_3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2387
Not Found: /images/footer_1.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:52:12] "GET /images/footer_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2393
[05/Apr/2020 06:54:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20820
[05/Apr/2020 06:54:11] "GET /static/index.css%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 1666
Not Found: /images/news_3.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:54:11] "GET /images/news_3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2387
Not Found: /images/footer_1.jpg
[05/Apr/2020 06:54:11] "GET /images/footer_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2393
```

some other elements of the page are also not displaying. I am unable to troubleshoot the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try remove {% %} from css

```
body{

background-image:static url('E:\coding\fyp\travello\images\whyl') ;

}
```

or try to move the css to html or put normal html image

Comment: it won't work since django dows not recognise hrml and css language.Jinja is required to run the files with django.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I suggest to add static tag to all images,follow the instructions made below and code will be working fine!!

Before changes: '`<div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>`

After changes: `<div class="background_image" style="background-image:  url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %})"></div>`